# Is it possible to host conversion.js on our own server

Tags: google-ads-api

Is it possible to host conversion.js file on our own server? we don't want to use "https://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js" to host it. I couldn't find the answer in google forums. The code is to track google adwords.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, but you should use some .php in back-end to update it regularly and by hosting it localy you will lose all advantages of Google CDN.